# Evaluate the Integral: $\int^2_1\frac{4y^2-7y-12}{y(y+2)(y-3)}dy$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, definite-integrals

I would like to know if my method when integrating and plugging in the bounds is sound or if I should change it. Please look over my attached work. Input and personal opinion is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Why would anyone want to look at your work? Seriously.

Comment: May be my integration method is flawed.

Comment: Your $A,B,C$ are correct. Your integral is correct too. Notice you can simplify further using $\log(4/3)=2\log(2)-\log(3)$.

Comment: @uniquesolution No need to be discourteous. Seriously.

Comment: Why are limits between $1$ and $2$ In your solution as opposed to what you posted ?

Comment: @uniquesolution Indeed, it is recommended that the OP show what they have tried so far.

Comment: @Chinny84 Argh, true, it's $1$ on the sheet, $0$ in the question! I guess it's a typo in the question.

Comment: A faster method to compute partial fractions when there is a simple root: multiply by the factor, and replace $y$ with the corresponding root. For instance, your $A$ is $(4y^2-7y-12)/(y+2)(y-3)$ where $y=0$, or $-12/-6=2$. Actually, it's equivalent to what you are doing, simply it's a one-liner ;-)

Comment: Also, when make the sub in the last two integrals you should change limits (to reduce confusion when checking) so for example use the limits for $u$ not $y$ for the integral wrt $u$.

Comment: what  kind of paper is this? :)